# Disable dragging of Alert Windows in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a problem with Flex.

How can I disable dragging of the Alert window in Flex?
I don't want the users to move my alert windows. What shall I do?

Thanks

```
var a:Alert=new Alert();
a.text="Alert Message";
PopUpManager.addPopUp(a,this,true);
```

Comment: Why do you care if your user drags the alert window? Whenever you want to change the platform default behaviour in such a way, you should really have a good reason. Otherwise it's just frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it by listening for the *mouseDown* event from the Alert window and calling the *stopImmediatePropagation()* method.

```
var a:Alert = new Alert();
a.text = "Alert message";
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, true);
PopUpManager.addPopUp(a, this, true);

private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dragging can be disable, by setting "isPopUp" property to "false".

```
var a:Alert = Alert.show("Alert message");
a.isPopUp = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you invoke the action using a.show, or Alert.show("text"), the window that appears is not movable.
Can you try that??